# Insert date works in SQL Developer but not through Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I face a problem whenever I want to insert a date from Java to my Oracle database.

Here is a sample of my Java code:

```
PreparedStatement prest = myConn.prepareStatement(
    "insert into QuickTicket (issueDate , pssngr_id , trip_number) values(?,?,?)") ;

String s = "2016/12/25" ;

prest.setString(1, s);
prest.setInt(2, passengerID);
prest.setInt(3, tripID);

prest.executeUpdate();
```

Exception:

> java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

However, when I put the same statement in SQL Developer:

```
insert into QuickTicket (issueDate , pssngr_id , trip_number) values
( '2016/12/25' , 1234567897 , 4 ) ;
```

I get no errors -- > 1 row inserted.

Any idea why?

Comment: dear down-voters :  you're always welcome to down-vote but please state a reason why so that i can improve my question.

Comment: try replacing the 1st line with this `PreparedStatement prest = myConn.prepareStatement("insert into QuickTicket (issueDate , pssngr_id , trip_number) values(?,?,?);") ;`

Comment: Please work on your formatting.

Comment: @the other me - did you try replacing the 1st line with my code that I presented in the above comment?

Comment: @MarrieteCowby12 - adding a semicolon will just change the error or ora-00911, as it's an invalid character in a single SQL statement.

Comment: @MarrieteCowby12 the semicolon is not the issue. I was passing a String and the database is expecting a date. Take a look at the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL Developer session and Java environment have different NLS settings; one expects the date in YYYY/MM/DD format, the other in something else. You could force the environments to match, but you won't always be able to control that, and it's better not to rely on NLS settings anyway.

You need to either specify the format as part of the insert statement using `to_date()`:

```
PreparedStatement prest = myConn.prepareStatement(
    "insert into QuickTicket (issueDate , pssngr_id , trip_number) values(to_date(?, 'YYYY/MM/DD'),?,?)") ;

String s = "2016/12/25" ;

prest.setString(1, s);
...
```

or preferably use a Date variable, and set it with `setDate()` rather than `setString()`, changing the format of your String [to what `valueOf()` expects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-), as JohnMatthewIanDavis pointed out:

```
PreparedStatement prest = myConn.prepareStatement(
    "insert into QuickTicket (issueDate , pssngr_id , trip_number) values(?,?,?)") ;

String s = "2016-12-25" ;

prest.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(s));
...
```

If you're actually trying to insert the current date you can get that from Java:

```
prest.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```

or more simply from within Oracle, using `sysdate` or `current_date` (for the server time and the client time, respectively; in this case probably server?):

```
PreparedStatement prest = myConn.prepareStatement(
    "insert into QuickTicket (issueDate , pssngr_id , trip_number) values(trunc(sysdate),?,?)") ;

prest.setInt(1, passengerID);
prest.setInt(2, tripID);
```

The `trunc()` sets the time of the inserted value to midnight. If you want to keep the time, just use plain `sysdate`.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing issueDate is a Date type in your database, which means you want to bind a Date and not a String

```
prest.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(s));
```

instead of

```
prest.setString(1, s);
```

it should work.

Comment: Actually you have to change the date "2016/12/25" to "2016-12-25", well.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-

Comment: You nailed it. I thought i would just pass a string and the database will handle it. A huge pile of thanks.